# Decrypt sysprep unattend.xml user password

Tags: codec, decryption

How do I decrypt user passwords that are encrypted and used in Windows 7 Sysprep unattend.xml file?

What Encryption method is used in this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a base64-encoded string. The way to make the original password visible is to unencode (decode) it. You can do this with a PowerShell script like this:

```
$encryptedpassword = "SQBKAHMALgBiAGwAbwBlAG0AMwBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA"
Write-Host [system.text.encoding]::Unicode.GetString([system.convert]::Frombase64string($encryptedpassword))
```

or use online base64 decoder like this: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: After you decode, get rid of `Password` at the end.

Comment: Nice snippet! There was a () missing somewhere, this worked for me: $encryptedpassword = "SQBKAHMALgBiAGwAbwBlAG0AMwBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA" $dPwD= ([system.text.encoding]::Unicode.GetString([system.convert]::Frombase64string($encryptedpassword)));write-host $dPwD.Substring(0,($dPwD.length-8))